# how to displace the graph along x-axis for 1 position left?

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

i need to displace graph. for 1 point left. i need it to start from zero. (chartarea.isstartedfromzero is set to true). but it is not zero. it is 1. can smb help me to solve my problem. is it possible at all? thanks.

Comment: i add data in such way chart1.series[0].points.addxy("x", y). it start from 1 not from 0

Comment: I added the mschart tag to your question hoping it was what you meant (I couldn't tell based on your question), if it wasn't my apologies. Either way please avoid tags in your question titles. We have a wide variety of tags available I'm sure one of them is appropriate.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot and what are X datapoints, not sure as what you mean by *1 point left* ?

Comment: screenshot is not alowed for beginners but i can post it to your mail

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/bjEQd6oR screenshot

Comment: first point should be at y-axis(x-axis == 0). but it lies at x-axis == 1. it means that this point does not belongs to y-axis. is it possible to put it at y-axis? (to displace for one point (position) left)

Answer (score 3):

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
```

This is the code you are looking for, since you dont wanna start with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try adjust this proerty:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset
```

For example:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
```